# Best option for packaging a Java CLI app for OS/X and Unix?

Tags: java, command-line-interface, executable-jar

What's the best option for packaging and distributing a command line application written in Java, targetting OS/X and Unix?

The executable jar option seems fairly robust, and my distribution doesn't need to be super fancy, so right now I'm just thinking of plonking a bash script next to that with the relevant java invocation and being done with it.

I'm wondering if there's something similar to python's [bdist](http://docs.python.org/distutils/builtdist.html) package that would let me easily make nice installers for both target platforms. Or if there's some more obvious way that I'm missing where I can turn the entire distribution in to a executable file that wraps the jar in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are providing a CLI application it may be easiest to just provide the script you already mentioned. I usually try to keep it self-contained, e. g. not referencing external paths / using only relative paths etc. And maybe a `readme.txt` file.

If you would like to provide a full-blown installer, you might want to take a look at [IzPack, a tool for generating installers for Java deliverables](http://izpack.org/). It also allows the wizard to run in console mode, if you do not have a graphical environment available for installation (see the "Features" page in the link above).

Comment: Thanks Axel, I went with the executable jar and a script in the end. Though it was worth asking in case there was some received correct way I wasn't aware of.